# How to configure proxy in multipass virtual machine

Tags: vpn, proxy, multipass

My host computer (macOS Monterey M1) needs to connect through a proxy, which I can configure by setting the address as an environment variable (among other places):

```
export https_proxy=http://.../
```

This allows me to run something like:

```
$> curl https://google.com
<HTML><HEAD>...
```

I'd like to run Focal 20.04 in a multipass virtual machine, which I've got all setup and launched, but it doesn't appear to see the network once inside the vm.

I've added the same `$https_proxy` to the `.bashrc` file, but either with it or without it the `curl` command still hangs.

I've also set up a "traditional" 20.04 vm using VMware Fusion (tech preview) and making those proxy environment changes worked and the network is visible.

However, I also tried setting up a vm using UTM, which I believe uses QEMU just like multipass, and I couldn't get that to ever properly work.  I didn't try that hard, but there weren't many resources, and I gave up and moved on to VMWare.

So are there any suggestions to get the proxy working in multipass?  Another complication, if it matters, is I'm also running a VPN using tunnelblick and OpenVPN on the host.

If it helps, I tested the multipass vm by turning off the host VPN and disabling the proxy environment and the vm sees the network as expected, so it's for certain an issue related to proxies and/or vpn.

Thanks!